# Infinite Loop on ngModelChange

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a list containing users, and i have an item that i want it to redirect me to a modal page.
My problem is as soon as my page is available, i get an infinite pop up of my modal, instead of going on my ion-select and select the item so i can get the pop up.

html

```
<ion-select interface="popover" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)"> 
  <ion-option>Bacon</ion-option>
  <ion-option  [value]="openConfig()"></ion-option>Black Olives</ion-option>
  <ion-option>Extra Cheese</ion-option>
  <ion-option>Mushrooms</ion-option>
  <ion-option>Pepperoni</ion-option>
  <ion-option>Sausage</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

ts

```
  onChange(value: any) {
    if (value === 'openConfig') {
      this.openConfig()
    }
  }

  openConfig() {
    this.modalCtrl.create('ConfigModal').present;
    console.log('heeey')
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting the `[value]` in the template is actually calling your `openConfig()` function, creating an infinite loop on the page load. To do what you're trying to do here you don't need to reference your `openConfig` function in the template at all.

`ion-select` uses the output event `ionChange`, which outputs the value of the `ion-option` selected.  So the normal way to do this in Ionic 3 would be something like this:

html:

`<ion-content padding>
  <ion-select interface="popover" [ngModel]="option" (ionChange)="onChange($event)"> 
    <ion-option>Bacon</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Black Olives</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Extra Cheese</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Mushrooms</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Pepperoni</ion-option>
    <ion-option>Sausage</ion-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-content>`

js:

```
onChange(value: any) {
  if (value === 'Black Olives') {
    this.openConfig()
  }
}

openConfig() {
  this.modalCtrl.create(ConfigModal).present();
}
```

Note that the value of an `ion-option` is simply the text of the label.  So that's what you should check for in your "onChange" function.

You have a couple of other unrelated typos, but I believe this addresses the question of your infinite loop.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you so much, i have another question, in my case, i have a list of users, so it need to get the id, is there a way to make a condition for my button ? cause when i select the Black Olives, instead of opening the modal it's throw me an error of undefined _id ( and open the modal ) i want it to ignore that this one don't have an _id

Comment: I don't know exactly how your app works but I'd just add on to the conditional.  i.e.  `if (value === 'Black Olives' && user != undefined) {` or something like that (how ever your logic for checking if you have a user object works).